# Is there a shortcut to Highpool City Center?

Tags: wasteland-2

Do you really have to run all the way up to elevator and watch elevation animation for 10th time again and again?

Lately I realized I can leave one party member at the entrance to save on return trip, but anyway running 5m to ask Ms.Preston if she's ready is a bit boring.

Any better options I missed?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Once you save Highpool from the Wreckers and assist Kate Preston in becoming mayor, she'll open the locked tunnel entrance for you which will take you back out, avoiding the elevator completely.  But before that, I don't think it's avoidable.

As a side note, I was able to gather enough support for Preston just staying up top.  Using surgeon skill on each of the people in the infirmary, finding a dog's owner, and putting out the house fire were some of the things I can recall.